# Google Search Console won't let me choose preferred domain because no-www isn't verified even though it is

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I already saw this question: [Why won't Webmaster Tools let me set a preferred domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33578/why-wont-webmaster-tools-let-me-set-a-preferred-domain-says-to-verify-but-it) and it didn't help

I want the preferred to be with www, and it tells me I need to verify `example.com` without www. But it is verified. So I removed it completely from my properties, that didn't work. So I tried to unverify it and gives me error: Couldn't unverify it.

How do I fix this message:

> Part of the process of setting a preferred domain is to verify that you own `https://example.com/`. Please verify `https://example.com/`

When both `https://example.com/` and `https://www.example.com/` are shown as verified?

Currently Google shows the non-www version of my website.

Comment: What do your canonical tags say? Are you redirecting to the www version of your pages?

Comment: Canonical tags and redirects shouldn't matter for choosing www vs no-www in GSC.  Google lets you choose a preferred when both are serving the same content.

Comment: Have you tried verifying all *four* versions of your site `http://`, `https://`, `http://www` and `https://www`?   I suspect you may have verified the `http://` version but not the `https://` version.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else will have that problem, here is the cause (For me at least):
I have an HTTPS website, so at first I added 2 properties: `https://example.com/` and `https://www.example.com/`, and these 2 alone were not enough, so I added 2 more properties: the non-HTTPS versions: `http://example.com/` and `http://www.example.com`/, and immediately after I added them I was able to choose a preferred domain.